# Updating UnstructredGrid after Adding Cell (VTK C++)

Tags: c++, graphics, vtk

**Current System (bottom-up):**

- **points** (vtkSmartPointer< vtkPoints >)
- **topology**(vtkSmartPointer< vtkCellArray >)
- **unGrid**(vtkSmartPointer< vtkUnstructuredGrid >)
- **mapper**(vtkSmartPointer< vtkDataSetMapper >)
- **actor**(vtkSmartPointer< vtkActor >)

**My Attempt to Add New Cell and Update:**

I have added a new cell to topology and am confused on how to update this system. It consists of existing points, so have tried:

```cpp
topology->InsertNextCell(newCell);
unGrid->GetCells()->Modified();
```

**Questions:**

- **What thing(s) do I need to update**(call **Modifed()** ) on, just unGrid?
- Since I need to specify the cell types when I SetCells() for unGrid,
  do I need to do this again when I add a new cell(since it could be of
  a new type)?

**Notes:**

- vtk 8.2.0(C++)
- Must use unstructured grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple error, just **replace:**

```
unGrid->GetCells()->Modified();
```

**With:**

```
unGrid->Modified();
```